# Spring and JUnit annotated tests: creating fixtures in separate transactions

Tags: hibernate, spring, junit, annotations

I am testing my Hibernate DAOs with Spring and JUnit.

I would like each test method to start with a pre-populated DB, i.e. the Java objects have been saved in the DB, in a Hibernate transaction that has already been committed. How can I do this?

With @After and @Before, methods execute in the same Hibernate transaction as the methods decorated with @Test and @Transactional (first level cache may not be flushed by the time the real test method starts). @BeforeTransaction and @AfterTransaction apparently cannot work with Hibernate because they don't create transactions even if the method is annotated with @Transactional in addition to @Before/AfterTransaction.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way could be to externalize your intialization logic to an external service with transactional methods which are executed from your @BeforeTransaction and @AfterTransaction annotated methods in the test class.

Another benefit of this approach is the reusability of initialization code across tests.

You could for example use the SpringJunit4ClassRunner like described [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management) like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"testContext.xml","services.xml"})
public class MyServiceTest {

    @Autowired    
    private TestDataService testDataService;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        testDataService.addTestData();
    }

    @Test
    public void testSomething() throws Exception {
         // ...
    }
}


public interface TestDataService {

    void addTestData();

}

public class TestDataServiceImpl implements TestDataService {

    @Transactional
    public void addTestData(){
        // TODO
    }

}
```

That's something we do in our Spring based projects.

Make sure the [transactional configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations) is correct. If you want to avoid the class/interface separation, then set proxy-target-class to true in the   element.

Comment: Thanks Timo, I like your answer, but I could not inject such an initialization service into my test object (simple DAOs and beans that do no depend on a Hibernate session factory work great though). I have the impression that the application context startup is not standard. Any idea of what might be going on?

Comment: With JUnit 4.5 and Spring 3, I cannot inject in my test classes services annotated with @Transactional. Services not annotated with @Transactional can be injected just fine though.

Comment: @Francois, do they simply not get injected or do they throw any Exception? Also do yo use Interface/Class separation? Autowired matches by type, not by name. I need some more information to help you.

Comment: Thanks Timo.

Do they simply not get injected or do they throw any Exception? They throw an exception when injected. If I list the beans from the application context, they are here, but casting them fails. If I remove all @Transaction annotations, it works.

Also do yo use Interface/Class separation? The TestSetup service family is entirely separate from the test classes.

The TestService family follows a simple singletons / autowire by type paradigm.

Comment: Ok, my guess is that something goes wrong with Spring AOP proxying, I posted an example that should work.

Comment: I think so too. Thanks for your help though. Your solution should work.

Answer (score 2):

[dbUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/) is a good framework for the job.

In short, it should be started from the `setUp()` method and it deletes all contents from specified tables, then fill them up with content from a XML file.

Else you can try to execute the `setUp()` method in a new transaction like this:

```
@Before
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void setUp() {
    // initial logic .. 
}
```